# ZingChart in Ember.js not displaying watermark

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an ember.js project in which I included a chart with [zingchart](https://www.zingchart.com/).
As the [Buy Page](https://www.zingchart.com/buy/) states, you must always display the watermark when using the free version.
However there is no watermark displayed and I connot find how to display one.

These are my renderOptions:

```
let _renderOptions = {
height: 400,
width: "100%",
events: {
    node_click: function (p) {
        console.log(p);
        Ember.$('tr').css('background-color', 'transparent');
        Ember.$('#' + p.scaletext + '-row').css('background-color', '#D29A52');
    }
},
data: {
    "type": "line",
    "series": [
        {
            "values": [2.55, 1.82, 1.36, 1.15, 1.20, 1.10, 0.95, 1.00, 1.20, 1.04], 'text': 'Einnahmen (in Mio €)'
        },
        {
            "values": [3.01, 2.62, 2.51, 1.75, 1.48, 1.48, 1.36, 1.56, 1.51, 1.37], 'text': 'Ausgaben (in Mio €)'
        }
    ],
    "scale-x": {
        "labels": [2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015],
        'item': {
            'font-size': '18'
        }
    },
    "scale-y": {
        'item': {
            'font-size': '16'
        }
    },
    "legend": {
        'background-color': 'transparent',
        'border-color': 'transparent',
        'margin-top': '55px',
        'margin-right': '50px',
        'item': {
            'font-size': '15'
        }
    },
},
defaults: {
    "palette": {
        "line": [
            ["#ffffff", "#C5914D", "#C5914D", "#C5914D"],
            ["#ffffff", "#856234", "#856234", "#856234"],
        ]
    },
    "graph": {
        "background-color": "transparent"
    }
}
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is displayed automatically and no need to do something more.

Please take a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/33b83cd981998851bb5f0c3bbe486d81)

At bottom right corner there is a trademark. The docs used to say it watermark. I think trademark is a better name ;)

Comment: thanks for your answer. That was what I thought as well. However on my page nothing is displayed...

Comment: Maybe you hide it by css somewhere. Anyway, you don't need to do more. It should be there automatically not manually.